# Копиляция .java в .class

Tags: java

Сразу скажу, что я не программист и не изучаю Java, просто возникла необходимость декомпилировать файл .class в .java и поменять в нём цифру.

Декомпилировать и изменить цифру получилось, а вот с обратной компиляцией начались беды, порывшись в интернете, понял, что нужно скачать jdk и использовать javac, это я и сделал, но при компиляции посыпались ошибки

(использовал команду javac -classpath industrialcraft_2_2.8.189_ex112.jar -Xlint:unchecked CableType.java),

https://pastebin.com/HsF63sPz - текст файла, который компилирую, изменил только строку 88 (изначально вместо 900000000 было 8192)
[image: Ошибки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кривой декомпилятор использовали.

Я проверил с [этим](http://www.javadecompilers.com/). Всё нормально работает. Инструкция такая:

1. Декомпилируем класс
2. Создаем папку например `myfolder`
3. В эту папку кидаем джарник
4. В этой папке создаем такую структуру каталогов: `ic2/core/block/wiring`
5. В каталог `wiring` кидаем класс с измененными циферками
6. В каталоге `myfolder` выполняем следующую команду: `javac -classpath industrialcraft_2_2.8.189_ex112.jar ic2/core/block/wiring/CableType.java`

Comment: Выполнил всё по вашей инструкции, к сожалению опять 7 ошибок, видимо у меня что-то не правильно настроено. Может я тогда вам кину класс, а вы скомпилируете? Если вам не сложно https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zmf742JpJLqo-V2EQF51GTzTE2inz1Sm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Нет, просто я не внимательный, всё получилось! Спасибо вам большое, вы меня очень выручили

Comment: Можете отметить мой ответ как правильный, если он Вам помог